# Find groups in SQL that are subsets of other groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below, containing a set of `Groups`, which contain unique (within themselves) `Values`. I'd like to find out which groups are complete subsets of other groups. Groups shouldn't be counted as subsets of themselves, of course.

GroupTable:

```
ID | Group | Value
==================
00 |  A    |   1
01 |  A    |   2
02 |  A    |   3
03 |  B    |   1
04 |  B    |   3
05 |  C    |   7
06 |  D    |   2
```

What I want (Every element in the `Smaller` groups is contained in the `Bigger` groups):

```
Smaller | Bigger
================
  B     |    A
  D     |    A
```

I've tried a few different queries, but I can't wrap my head around how to require *every* element in the `Bigger` group to be in the `Samller` group.

The best I've been able to do is this, which should find groups which contain *any* matching `Value` in another group. How can I turn the *any* to an *all*?

```
-- Groups where G1 ⊆ G2
SELECT  G1.Group, G2.Group
FROM GroupTable G1
JOIN GroupTable G2 ON G2.Group <> G1.Group
WHERE G1.Value = G2.Value
GROUP BY G1.Group, G2.Group;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL example below first joins the [Group]'s to others with the same [Value]'s.

Similar to Sergio Prats answer, when the total unique values of a joined [Group] is the same as the total unique values such [Group] has in total, then keep that as a [Smaller].

The CTE with the totals is used for the purpose of re-use in the joins.

And the `top 1 with ties` is used to keep only the biggest [Bigger]

```sql
declare @GroupTable table (ID int identity(1,1), [Group] char(1), Value int);

insert into @GroupTable ([Group], Value) values
('A',1),('A',2),('A',3),('B',1),('B',3),('C',7),('D',2),('E',3);

;with CTE as
(
    select [Group], count(distinct [Value]) as Total 
    from @GroupTable
    group by [Group]
)
select top 1 with ties 
Q1.Group1 as [Smaller], 
Q1.Group2 as [Bigger]
from 
(
    select 
    t1.[Group] as Group1, 
    t2.[Group] as Group2, 
    count(distinct t1.Value) as Total1
    from @GroupTable t1
    join @GroupTable t2 ON (t1.Value = t2.Value AND t1.[Group] != t2.[Group])
    group by t1.[Group], t2.[Group]
) Q1
join CTE c1 on (Q1.Group1 = c1.[Group] and Q1.Total1 = c1.Total)
left join CTE c2 on (Q1.Group2 = c2.[Group])
order by c2.Total desc, Q1.Group2;
```

Returns:

```
Smaller Bigger
B       A
D       A
E       A
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no duplicate values (as your question specifies), then you are very close.  You basically need a `left join` and `having` clause:

```
select gt.group as smaller_group, gr2.group as bigger_group
from grouptable gt left join
     grouptable gt2
     on gt2.value = gt.value and
        gt2.group <> gt.group
group by gt.group, gr2.group
having count(*) = count(gt2.group);
```

The `having` clause is saying that the number of values for a given group matches the number in the second group.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no duplicates per Group and value you can try this:

```
SELECT G1.[Group] as smaller, G2.[Group] AS bigger FROM 
(SELECT [Group], count(*) AS Num FROM  GroupTable GROUP BY [Group]) G1 
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT A1.[Group], A2.[Group] as SmallGroup, count(*) AS Num2 
    FROM GroupTable A1  INNER JOIN  GroupTable A2 ON
    A1.[Value] = A2.[Value] 
    WHERE A1.[Group] <> A2.[Group]
    GROUP BY A1.[Group], A2.[Group] ) G2
    ON G1.[Group] = G2.SmallGroup 
    WHERE Num2 = Num
```